# Wanting to start a Star Wars D&D campaign, but I want to really have deep political depth

Tags: gm-techniques, world-building, star-wars

I feel good as far as the star wars base setting, however I am struggling with how to add political depth to it. I would like to add some tough decisions that could change the way the game plays entirely. Would it be better to start my own political groups or look more into the star wars lore for help? Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the first time I have done my own story as a DM.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. Because Stack Exchange is a Q&A site, not a traditional discussion forum, this may get closed as being too opinion-based for its format. Whether or not it gets closed, the [chat] is always open if you want to discuss RPG things in a less structured format once you have 20+ rep on any SE site. (I'm rather curious why you're using the D&D engine for what sounds like a political thriller space opera, and would love to hear about it in chat!)